# to make div width equal to its sibling?

Tags: html, css

I have a panel , inside which there is a header and a table. If table width can increase dynamically based on data we are passing . So I have set Overflow of panel to auto . Now I want to adjust width of header in case of overflow i.e. it should take 100% width.
Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DeoD/4z4a3fwy/

```
 <div class="resultPanel">
    <h3 class="title">Title</h3>

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>                    
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>                    
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Just made some changes in the code. I think it will be useful and need not use jQuery

```
<div class="resultPanel">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3"><h3 class="title">Title</h3></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>data</td>                    
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data</td>                    
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>        
 </div>


.resultPanel {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 500px;
}
.title {
  background-color: gray;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.table{
    width:700px;
}
```

[Fiddle Refer](http://jsfiddle.net/4z4a3fwy/15/)

i have put h3 inside

and for h3 set width to 100% in css

Answer (score 0):

You can set width of the header to same as width of the table like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.title').css('width',$('.table').width());  
});
```

Here is [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4z4a3fwy/23/)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to create a function that checks the width of the table.
If width of the table is greater than the width of .resultPanel, then adjust .resultPanel width to the width of table:

```js
function adjustResultPanel(){
    var tableWidth = $('.table').width();
    var resultPanelWidth = $('.resultPanel').width();
    if ( tableWidth > resultPanelWidth ){
        $('.resultPanel').width(tableWidth)
    } 
}


$(function(){

  adjustResultPanel();

});
```

your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4z4a3fwy/19/

Answer (score 0):

set title width to 100%

```
 .title {
      background-color: gray;
      line-height: 40px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 0px;
        width:100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution with minimal change is to put your table (and h3) in a div with `display: inline-block`

```
<div class="resultPanel">
    <div style='display: inline-block'>
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>data</td>                    
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data</td>                    
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
            </table>   
    </div>
 </div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/4z4a3fwy/27/